# youtube-dl doesn't report back the correct downloaded file

Tags: python, youtube, youtube-dl

I'm using youtube-dl in a Python program as a module and not from the command line. It works just fine except for when I download (ironically) some YouTube videos - specifically, the ones where the audio is encoded as a separate file from the video. Basically, I need the name of the final file, however I get the names of the two files before remuxing. According to the youtube-dl documentation, you can get the final filename using hooks:

filename: The final filename (always present)

tmpfilename: The filename we're currently writing to

seems 'filename' should get me the name of the file that is created from the audio and video that was downloaded and combined. But it does not do that.

here is my code:

```
def my_hook(d):
    if d['status'] == 'finished':
    print "\nYour video has been downloaded!"
    filelocation = d['filename']
    print filelocation

def download_video(url, archival_location, asset):
    global mountpoint

    # Put Location and filename to save in a variable
    destination = archival_location + asset + ".%(ext)s"
    # options for youtubedl
    ydl_opts = {
        'logger' : MyLogger(),
        'progress_hooks': [my_hook],
        'outtmpl' : destination
    }
    try:
        # Lets download it now
        with YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
            ydl.download([url])
            print ""
    except:
        print "Error with downloader. Most likely Unsupported URL"
        #check and see if we mounted a drive
        if mounted:
            unmount(mountpoint)
        # Exit the program           
        exit()
```

There is more to the program but this is the pertinent bit. Here is the output when downloading a video from YouTube:

> Your video has been downloaded!
>   /Volumes/RR261-GOING-POSTAL_1/RR261_Archival_Footage/RR261_A999_Erase_Please.f243.webm
>
> Your video has been downloaded!
>   /Volumes/RR261-GOING-POSTAL_1/RR261_Archival_Footage/RR261_A999_Erase_Please.f141.m4a

Now my program will fail because the variable `filelocation` points to the m4a file that will be gone once ffmpeg does its thing. How do I get youtube-dl to report the final file? Or am I going about this the wrong way? Is there another way to get the path and filename of what ffmpeg has created? My program doesn't call ffmpeg, the youtube-dl module does, and I don't see what it's doing from stdout.

Comment: If the documented hook API doesn't call anything you can hook when it muxes the file together, there's obviously no way to get that information from the documented API. But you've got the source, so you can add another hook yourself. Or you can just file a feature request at the GitHub repo.

Comment: But from a quick glance at [the options](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/blob/master/youtube_dl/YoutubeDL.py#L92), it looks like it should be trivial to just wrap the ffmpeg postprocessor in your own subclass that calls the super and then stores or prints the `out_path`.

Comment: I'm Kind of a novice programmer. Not sure what wrapping the ffmpeg postprocessor in a subclass means. If its modifying the youtube-dl source that is not ideal because when they add new sites and i update i'll have to re-modify each time. Or could i wrap ffmpeg in a subclass without touching the youtube-dl source?

Comment: You're going to have to read the code, and understand it well enough to figure out if it provides a documented way for you to substitute your own subclass, or if you have to monkeypatch it. If you can't do that, you can't do this project (unless you go learn a lot more Python, find a collaborator, or hire someone).